# EF Core Migrations InsertData on arbitrary locations and data length

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I'm creating a Database with a lot of seed data. This data that is constant and will not be manipulated. I've set all relations correctly.

But when I create the Migration with the

```
dotnet ef migrations add migrationname
```

(or the package manager console)

but here's where the trouble starts.

The Seed Data is split and placed in a rather arbitrary way.

For example table a and table b and a table c.

The Primary Key in table c consists of a merged key of both foreign keys from table a and b.

My problem is now that, for some reason, the generated migration script now holds entries like this.

```
migrationBuilder.InsertData(/* 1 row from table c */)

migrationBuilder.InsertData(/* 4 rows from table a */)

migrationBuilder.InsertData(/* 3 rows from table b */)

migrationBuilder.InsertData(/* 5 row from table c */)
```

Naturally I get trouble on the first line as it tries to insert a row that uses a foreign key that does yet exists.

I'm aware that I could just change the script by hand. But the amount does not merit a manual change.

Anyone has any ideas?

Is there any way where I can determine the order in which the seed data in the migration script is generated?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].